# Wordpress site on Hostgator server doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system

I have a site using Wordpress and a custom built theme and have migrated the site and database to my Hostgator server. I've also changed the site option and home url (http://cebuproperties.jeffreyteruel.com), but when I get to the homepage I get an Warning and Fatal Error. However, if I go to another page, say http://cebuproperties.jeffreyteruel.com/updates with all the links and page working properly. It's just my homepage which is the problem. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `wp-includes/random_compat/random.php` may be missing on the new server. This sort of thing can be caused by upgrade or server migration. One fix is to replace all the core WordPress files with a fresh install.

1. Create a backup of all files and the database
2. Delete all files and folders except for the folder `wp-content`. It contains all the files for your theme and plugin so you don't want to delete it.
3. Replace all the WordPress files in the install download EXCEPT for `wp-content`.
4. Update `wp-config.php` with your database credentials (look in your current `wp-config.php` file).
5. You may need to update the database (once you login to admin it will tell you if so).

Comment: Just did it and also removed Zen Cache Plugin. Realized it was a problem with the cache and with refresh it worked well.